# Arkham Origins PC- Saving Problem

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I have played through Arkham Origins on the PC twice now. Both times I get to a point where the saving icon appears in the bottom right. I cannot find an option to save manually, and so I press exit. However, whenever I attempt to resume the game, there is no record of a save file that is at the point that I was at when I stopped playing. This is extremely frustrating, as I have to restart every time. Please help!

Answer (score -1):

In the folder where you installed it , there is a folder called " Saves " a number that happens .